# How to Create Dot Function in Dart or Flutter

Tags: dart

Suppose I want to convert a UNIX integer into DateTime Format when called upon.
(That's just an example)
I want to create a function just like `.toUpperCase();` , `.toString();` where function takes that particular item as argument without writing inside brackets. I did try going inside these default core functions but didn't help.

How do I do that for custom functions?
right now I'm here:

```
//------------- main()----------//

void main() {
  int unixDT = 1619691181;
// print(unixDT.toDateString()); //<-----this is what I'm looking for

}

//------- This is a function that should be in another-separate dart file-------//

String toDateString(int dt) {
  DateTime datetime = new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(dt);
  return datetime.toString();
}
```

*If you need clarification, please comment down. This is my very **first question on StackOverflow** so I apologize for mistakes if any.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for [extension methods](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#extension-methods):

```
void main() {
  const unixDT = 1619691181;
  print(unixDT.toDateString()); // 1970-01-19 18:54:51.181
}

extension IntToDateStringExtension on int {
  String toDateString() => DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(this).toString();
}
```

Comment: Yup. This is it. Thanks a lot for quick help.

Comment: @Hardik No problem. Please accept my answer if there are no further clarification. You are of course also welcome to accept another answer if you find it better suited.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `extension methods` for this situations. You can add a method in `Integer`. For more details https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `this` to refer to same object that is calling that method, Hope that will help

Comment: How would that even work? Can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: I got your hint.
@julemand101 just helped with that keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [extension methods](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods)

Example:

```
extension ExtendedDynamic on dynamic {
 double toDouble() {
   final sValue = this?.toString() ?? '';
   final double parsedValue = double?.tryParse(sValue) ?? 0.0;
   return parsedValue;
 }
}

void someMethod() {
  final dynamic test = 0.0;
  print(test.toDouble());
}
```

In your case it will be like this:

```
extension ExtendedInt on int {
 String toDateString() {
  final dateString = 'your code...';
  return dateString;
 }
}

void someMethod() {
 int unixDT = 1619691181;
 print(unixDT.toDateString());
}
```

**Important thing : Wherever you want to use this extension, you must import it**

```
import 'package:yourProject/extensions/int_extention.dart';
```